# I want my voice to sound like a parot

Tags: software

What app is there that can make my voice sound like a parot

Comment: You'll need to be more descriptive with what you think makes something sound like a parrot (EQ? just affectation? etc.)

Comment: Buy a parrot. Talk to it and teach it to say what you want. Record it.
Job Done.

Answer (score 3):

There's no substitute for good voice acting, but the talking parrots and cockatoos I hear on YouTube generally have slightly higher vocal resonances than natural. Upward pitch shifting and/or formant shifting may help improve realism if your voice is too deep for the task.

Comment: Thanks! Would you have any recommendations for approaches or exercises that bolster 'voice acting' skills in this regard?

Comment: Sorry, I have no expertise in voice acting, and such advice is really beyond the scope of a sound design forum. Practice imitating some YouTube clips, I guess?